# Copy data from multiple sheets to another workbook when condition is met

Tags: excel, vba

How could I copy multiple sheets to another workbook using VBA.

The condition is `Cells(I,4)` is nonblank. My input file is named "Mergefile" and my ouput file is named "Detail OD". The ouput data will be in sheets("Data").

And I want to copy range B to range J if condition is met. My example file is below, I just want to copy nonblank data and ignore the filtered row.

[image]

Comment: PS: the input file link: "D:\Khoi-Personal\PV\OD data"

Comment: the ouput file link :"D:\Khoi-Personal\PV\Detail OD- follow up OD 07.2022\07.2022\"

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Where do you run into troubles? Please don't include additional information in comments, edit your question instead.